# How to add fetchpriority parameter to images in the media library?

Tags: custom-field

I want to add a custom field called fetchpriority to the images in the media gallery. This parameter should be added to the image when it is inserted in a post.

Ex: I have an image called logo.png. This is uploaded to the media gallery. I edit the image and put **high** in the value. Now when the image is inserted in the post, it looks like `<img src="logo.png" fetchpriority="high">`

How do we achieve this? This is a valuable addition to achieving a good LCP score in the PageSpeed Insights.